# 6X6 grid, 3 Player Tic Tac Toe game Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm very new to Python and I have to create a tic tac toe game with 3 players, 'X', 'O' and 'Y'. The grid has to be 6x6 instead of the normal 3x3. I have been having a lot of trouble with this and I'm very unsure how to do it. I have a 2 player 3x3 game working but implementing another player and validating the wins is becoming more tedious than I previously expected. I need help with validating a win. I haven't written the code to check for a diagonal win because I want to get everything else working before I do that. This is what I have so far but it's not correct. It's not printing out the values entered and when I do enter a value it says X has won straight away. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me. Thanks!

```
grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

def get_state(grid, row, col):
occupant = grid[col-1][row-1]
if occupant == 1:
    return 'X'
if occupant == 2:
    return 'O'
if occupant == 3:
    return 'Y'
return ' '

def set_state(grid, row, col, player):
if player == 'X':
    occupant = 1
elif player == 'O':
    occupant = 2
elif player == 'Y':
    occupant = 3
grid[col-1][row-1] = occupant

def is_winner(grid):
if grid[0][0] == grid[0][1] == grid [0][2]:
    return True
if grid[0][1] == grid[0][2] == grid [0][3]:
    return True
if grid[0][2] == grid[0][3] == grid [0][4]:
    return True
if grid[0][3] == grid[0][4] == grid [0][5]:
    return True
if grid[1][0] == grid[1][1] == grid [1][2]:
    return True
if grid[1][1] == grid[1][2] == grid [1][3]:
    return True
if grid[1][2] == grid[1][3] == grid [1][4]:
    return True
if grid[1][3] == grid[1][4] == grid [1][5]:
    return True
if grid[2][0] == grid[2][1] == grid [2][2]:
    return True
if grid[2][1] == grid[2][2] == grid [2][3]:
    return True
if grid[2][2] == grid[2][3] == grid [2][4]:
    return True
if grid[2][3] == grid[2][4] == grid [2][5]:
    return True
if grid[3][0] == grid[3][1] == grid [3][2]:
    return True
if grid[3][1] == grid[3][2] == grid [3][3]:
    return True
if grid[3][2] == grid[3][3] == grid [3][4]:
    return True
if grid[3][3] == grid[3][4] == grid [3][5]:
    return True
if grid[4][0] == grid[4][1] == grid [4][2]:
    return True
if grid[4][1] == grid[4][2] == grid [4][3]:
    return True
if grid[4][2] == grid[4][3] == grid [4][4]:
    return True
if grid[4][3] == grid[4][4] == grid [4][5]:
    return True
if grid[5][0] == grid[5][1] == grid [5][2]:
    return True
if grid[5][1] == grid[5][2] == grid [5][3]:
    return True
if grid[5][2] == grid[5][3] == grid [5][4]:
    return True
if grid[5][3] == grid[5][4] == grid [5][5]:
    return True
if grid[0][0] == grid[1][0] == grid [2][0]:
    return True
if grid[1][0] == grid[2][0] == grid [3][0]:
    return True
if grid[2][0] == grid[3][0] == grid [4][0]:
    return True
if grid[3][0] == grid[4][0] == grid [5][0]:
    return True
if grid[0][1] == grid[1][1] == grid [2][1]:
    return True
if grid[1][1] == grid[2][1] == grid [3][1]:
    return True
if grid[2][1] == grid[3][1] == grid [4][1]:
    return True
if grid[3][1] == grid[4][1] == grid [5][1]:
    return True
if grid[0][2] == grid[1][2] == grid [2][2]:
    return True
if grid[1][2] == grid[2][2] == grid [3][2]:
    return True
if grid[2][2] == grid[3][2] == grid [4][2]:
    return True
if grid[3][2] == grid[4][2] == grid [5][2]:
    return True
if grid[0][3] == grid[1][3] == grid [2][3]:
    return True
if grid[1][3] == grid[2][3] == grid [3][3]:
    return True
if grid[2][3] == grid[3][3] == grid [4][3]:
    return True
if grid[3][3] == grid[4][3] == grid [5][3]:
    return True
if grid[0][4] == grid[1][4] == grid [2][4]:
    return True
if grid[1][4] == grid[2][4] == grid [3][4]:
    return True
if grid[2][4] == grid[3][4] == grid [4][4]:
    return True
if grid[3][4] == grid[4][4] == grid [5][4]:
    return True
if grid[0][5] == grid[1][5] == grid [2][5]:
    return True
if grid[1][5] == grid[2][5] == grid [3][5]:
    return True
if grid[2][5] == grid[3][5] == grid [4][5]:
    return True
if grid[3][5] == grid[4][5] == grid [5][5]:
    return True
return False


def print_grid(grid):
print_row(grid,1)
print('-----------')
print_row(grid,2)
print('-----------')
print_row(grid,4)
print('-----------')
print_row(grid,4)
print('-----------')
print_row(grid,5)
print('-----------')
print_row(grid,6)




def print_row(grid, row):
output = get_state(grid,row,1)
output += '|' + get_state(grid, row, 2)
output += '|' + get_state(grid, row, 3)
output += '|' + get_state(grid, row, 4)
output += '|' + get_state(grid, row, 5)
output += '|' + get_state(grid, row, 5)
print (output)


ongoing = True
currentPlayer = 'X'
spaces = 36

while ongoing:
print_grid(grid)
print (currentPlayer + "'s turn")
print("Column?")
col = int(input())
print("Row?")
row = int(input())
current = get_state(grid,row,col)
if current != ' ':
    print ("That spot is taken!")
else:
    set_state(grid, row, col, currentPlayer)
    spaces -= 1
    if is_winner(grid):
        print (currentPlayer + "'s wins!")
        ongoing = False
    else:
        if currentPlayer == 'X':
            currentPlayer = 'O'
        elif currentPlayer == 'O':
            curentPlayer = 'Y'
        elif currentPlayer == 'Y':
            currentPlayer = 'X'

    if spaces == 0:
        print("Stalemate!")
        ongong = False
```

Answer (score 2):

The `is_winner(grid)` function checks if 3 of the grid cells are the same. You initialized the grid to be 0, so the first player would always 'win'. One fix I suggest would be to initialize the list with different values. Another one would be to check (after finding that 3 cells are same) the values of the grid:

```
if grid[0][0] == grid[0][1] == grid[0][2]:
    return grid[0][0] in ['X', 'O', 'Y']
```

Comment: So should I change every line in is_winner(grid) to that? or at the top where I initialized grid to be                                                                                 'grid = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], ...'

Comment: @user3328281 Whatever you see fit - either initialize everything as a unique number, or change every line. I prefer the one with less work (initializing with unique numbers).

Comment: returning like this is not a good idea because it would immediately return false, you should check for if the cell is a good cell before returning

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by chucksys is good, although I would do it in a slightly different way. You need to determine that the 3 cells are the same, and not empty - so just check against your default value.

```
if grid[0][0] == grid[0][1] == grid[0][2] != 0:
    return True
```

Comment: thank you. That solves my validation problem! For some reason my program keeps asking for O's input even after I've entered it. The O is going into the system but it's not printing out on the screen. It says O has won if I put 3 in a row so that works. Any idea on why it doesn't print out or switch player? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

good luck with your game it's fun !!!! You can leave the code as it is. just make a different grid. one that contains a different value in every cell. That will prevent you from rewriting a lot of the game. At the beginning add the following code:
`grid = []
inner = []
b = 10
for i in xrange(6):
    for ii in xrange(6):
        inner.append(b)
        b += 1
    grid.append(inner)
    inner = list()`

This will make your grid, error proof from your checker function `is_winner`

There is also one small bug. `curentPlayer = 'Y'`
 change to `currentPlayer = 'Y'` near the end of the code

Comment: Thanks! So instead of having my big grid at the very top put in what you have there?

Comment: yes, exactly. tested it on my pc and it works fine ! just remember to change that  curentPlayer   to  currentPlayer . missed one r there . also you might want to add a  print grid at the end of my above code, just to see what happened to it. best of luck !!!

Comment: Fantastic that works perfectly. Yeh I fixed the bugs there and added the print_grid at the end. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!